# How to use the WinInet API from Java?

Tags: java, proxy, settings, wininet, internet-connection

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283027/whats-the-format-of-the-defaultconnectionsettings-value-in-the-windows-registry/4283310#4283310) to an earlier question of mine, the [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383630%28VS.85%29.aspx) Windows API is the correct way to read and write internet connection settings in Windows. How can I use this API from Java? I'd prefer a free, open-source solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's always JNI and JNA, but if you don't already know C or C++ there'll be a learning curve involved, especially with JNI: [JNI Reference](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/), [JNA Site](https://github.com/twall/jna/)

Answer (score 1):

Over the last months I had to mix with my Java project some C, C++ and Win32 alternatives for native access. After a lot work with JNA and recently with JInvoke for such integration, I can tell you that JInvoke is a little mature than JNA. Even JInvoke be older than JNA, I found its syntax more concise and simple. Sorry for those who loves JNA but using JInvoke I could literally hook the windows api from Java.

Comment: Notice that JInvoke has been discontinued a long time, I don't know exactly how long, but even so it's a good hook tool for native access. Other good alternative would be Python, which has a powerful win32 api as well as the ability to be mixed up with or from java code through Jython.

Answer (score 0):

I see there's a commercial library called [JInvoke](http://www.jinvoke.com/) that:

> enables Java developers to easily
> invoke native methods (such as the
> Win32 API or C-based Windows DLLs and
> Unix dynamic libraries) with pure Java
> code.

However I'd prefer something free and specifically targetted at the WinInet API.

Comment: Don't answer your own question. Edit the original, or comment on it.

Comment: From the FAQ: "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question". I agree that clarifications etc shouldn't take the form of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JACOB project

> JACOB is a JAVA-COM Bridge that allows
>   you to call COM Automation components
>   from Java. It uses JNI to make native
>   calls to the COM libraries. JACOB runs
>   on x86 and x64 environments supporting
>   32 bit and 64 bit JVMs

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/